# Fazer uma consulta da tabela wp_postmeta usando wpdb do wodpress

Tags: wordpress

Como eu faço para imprimir na página uma consulta da tabela `wp_postmeta` filtrando pela `meta_key` usando `wpdb` do `wordpress`? Já com a estrutura certa. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

A classe `wpdb` proporciona uma interface direta com o banco. Usando um exemplo do próprio [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb):

```
<?php
// set the meta_key to the appropriate custom field meta key
$meta_key = 'miles';
$allmiles = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
        SELECT sum(meta_value) 
        FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
        WHERE meta_key = %s
    ", 
    $meta_key
) );
echo "<p>Total miles is {$allmiles}</p>";
?>
```

Claro que aqui você pode alterar o `meta_key` e aquilo que você quer selecionar (no caso, o `sum(meta_value)`) pra aquilo que melhor lhe atender.

Eu, particularmente, não sou muito adepto de bagunçar com as globais do wp. A própria documentação da classe é cheia de avisos para o uso com cautela. De qualquer forma, existem muitas maneiras de se interagir com a metadata do wordpress, uma delas, é o método[`get_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), mas claro que isso varia de caso pra caso.

Comment: Com certeza a melhor opção é get_post_meta...